# Android web service response JSON with many Base64 String not working

Tags: android, json

In my project I call a URLusing HttpClient and get a JSON response with 15-20 Base64 String. The HttpClient Code is following.

```
public static JSONObject TestHttpPost(String url,
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in ["
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + "ms]");
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        try {

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String resultString = convertStreamToString(rd);
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
            Log.i(TAG, "<JSONObject>\n" + jsonObjRecv.toString()
                    + "\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(BufferedReader reader) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I am facing the following roblems

1. When ever i process the response using convertStreamToString() , i am unable to get the whole response .

2 As the Base64 string size is too big , StringBuilder  is unable to store the whole images String . The function just return a small part of the JSON. And it wil take too much time to process.

Comment: use stream base json reader. (also how many is many ? what do you mean "unable"?)

Comment: If you'd post your code, perhaps somebody could help you.

Comment: I have post my code . Please check it and give me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Log.i() truncates the value of the string after a certain number of characters. You probably received the string, but are unable to print it. Print the characters in chunks to get around the problem. The ring buffer allocated to logcat is 64k.

Comment: Can plz tell me what should i actually do to get the whole data? And it also takes too much time

Comment: Use the option logcat -f some_log_file.log or use your_log_string.substring() to print out the log in chunks

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it useful. Others who have the same problem will stumble across this post later and can use the solution.